# How to read in multiple names and numbers from a file?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

Hej! I need to be able to read in 5 variables from a file per line, the lines are formatted as such with different names

```
MIKE           ,CHENAULT       , 82 , 24 , 90
```

I cant seem to figure out how to read in each word and integer separately, I thought about using a character array for the first name as I need to then output them like so

```
Jones,J  -----   95
```

The number would be calculated by a formula, but I don't know how to grab the 5 different variables from a line. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a `Person` class which holds the first name, last name, and three numbers as data members. Then you can define an extractor that you can use to facilitate input:

```
struct Person
{
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& p); // for input
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p);
                                                                  // for output
private:
    std::string first, last;
    int a, b, c;
};

// definition of the extractor
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& p)
{
    char comma;
    is >> p.first >> comma >> p.last >> comma;
    is >> p.a     >> comma >> p.b    >> comma >> p.c;

    return is;
}
```

Now you can create your array (or vector) that holds 1000 `Person` instances:

```
std::vector<Person> v;

Person p;
while (file >> p)
{
    v.push_back(p);
}
```

Later on when you want to do an output, you can use the inserter you defined. For example:

```
std::cout << v[5];
```

Comment: Well the spaces don't matter but would the ctype class ignore the "," still don't understand how it would grab (first last a, b, c) unless this "if (file >> first >> last >> a >> b)" does it?

Comment: @user2967151 Yes, it will ignore the comma as well.

Comment: what is vector and v declared as? and where? Also is "file" your ifstream varible?

Comment: The vector acts as a table for classifying characters. And `file` is your file stream.

Comment: I seem to be getting an issue from "v" and "vector" since "v" is undeclared and "vector" namespace std has no member "vector". Sorry for being quite incompetent, this was hardly covered in my courses. Also for the file part, is this even using fstream? Since ive been reading in my files by using a ifstream varible called inFile and the actual file is called input.txt at C:

Comment: @user2967151 Okay. If this is for your course I should probably post something a little more simple (but something that works). Give me a moment.

Comment: @user2967151 Will there always be 3 numbers after the words or is it unspecified?

Comment: There is a file of 1000 names with 3 numbers following it, like so      `MIKE           ,CHENAULT       , 82 , 24 , 90 
JANET          ,THOMPSON       , 61 , 75 , 52 `  Would you like a pastebin of it? Yes they are

Comment: @user2967151 And these are all on separate lines?

Comment: Yeah they are all on separate lines, would you like a pastebin of it?

Comment: here! http://pastebin.com/JMTXt0Sv Thanks for helping me by they way, much appreciated

Comment: @user2967151 No problem. I just edited. Check it out and let me know if there are any problems or if you have questions.

Comment: I seem to be having some issues implementing your code, mind taking a look at what I've got so far? http://pastebin.com/xVacGzz5

Comment: @user2967151 What are these "issues" of which you speak? Are you getting errors? :-)

Comment: Well, yeah, I seem to be gettting issues with vector and v, Im pretty much trying to do this somehow. Im probably doing this wrong though. http://pastebin.com/F5E3VSZZ

Comment: @user2967151 `std::vector` is provided through the `<vector>` header, so you must include that. Moreover, in the example in your comment, the vector is *inside* the for loop statement, which means every time the for loop runs there will be a new empty vector created. We don't want that. Just place it outside the vector. Moreover,`Person().a` should be `p.a`. [Let me show you with an example.](http://pastebin.com/Fp1bWz0E)

Comment: Would the inserter be inside the for loop? Also I would be writing to the output file using outFile >> and not cout to the console.

Comment: @user2967151 Yes, we're performing an extraction and we put it inside the `if` statement because if the `if` statement runs that means the extraction was successful, and we can `push_back()` the object to the vector. And its fine with whatever you use for output. You could do `cout << v[i]` or `outFile << v[i]` it makes no difference.

Comment: Alright I think ive got it? Just not sure how to format the whole thing. [Take a look see?](http://pastebin.com/LC5fphT0)

Comment: I also am getting an error with `is >> p.first >> comma >> p.last >> comma;` the `is` is getting a "no operator ">>" matches these operands" error

Comment: @user2967151 What is the difference between those two code snippets you are comparing? Moreover, can yo show more of that error?

Comment: well in the first one the std:ostream and second outFile for loop are outside the forloop for v.push_back, and the other they are inside it. And its a error C2679 at line 57 which is ` is >> p.first >> comma >> p.last >> comma;`

Comment: @user2967151 I still don't follow what you're saying. And can you show me the entire error message please? Better yet, can you [post your full program here](http://stacked-crooked) so that I can run it?

Comment: Well here is the error, http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/76/41/7641646bff7ec7612e1797962cc6cbd0.png

Comment: And here is the full program, you may have an issue with the file part though. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5277e0b71f3c77d

Comment: @user2967151 You can't define functions within other functions, so put the definition of the inserter right after where you defined the extractor. [Try this code now.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a78529de90912866)

Comment: Ahh, well that makes more sense! And well it runs smoothly, but for some reason nothing happens, the quiz1output.txt doesnt update for some reason.

Comment: Oops, Nevermind it doest run, [this seems why](http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/19/74/1974cf084613997bdc983fa408bfdf33.png)

Comment: Wow, stupid ass mistake on my part, I forgot to include string and istream.... super face palm.

Comment: Pretty much! The only problem is trying to figure out how to convert the first name to a first initial to be displayed like `Jones,J ----- 123` So far ive got [this](http://pastebin.com/QxQyQHt6) but i get a "string subset out of range" error

Comment: @user2967151 The size should be `first.size()` because `first` is a `std::string` object so `sizeof` doesn't work like you think it would. Also, all you have to do is `char initial = first[0];` and you've got the first character.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea if that would matter or not, or that you could do just char initial = p.first[0]! Anyways its working perfectly now! outputs `CHENAULT,M  -----  286` and the like for the whole list! I must thank you tremendously for all your help and tolerating my lack in proper coding education. Ill be sure to make sure this code goes to good use in the future! Again thank you very much!

Comment: @ThereFour No problem at all! I enjoy helping. :)